# How to get array from external page in php

Tags: php

I've already done this once, but cannot for the life of me figure out how I did it.  I think it took about 5 lines of code.

I just want to take the array this URL outputs: http://ridetimes.co.uk/queue-times.php and then I would like to loop through the array and output each field.

Comment: this is json format. use json_decode to convert this format to php array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try

```
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ridetimes.co.uk/queue-times.php"), true);
```

Then for part to to output

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th><?= implode("</th><th>", array_map("htmlspecialchars",array_map("ucwords", array_keys($array[0])))) ?></th><tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php foreach($array as $row): ?>
    <tr><td><?= implode("</td><td>", array_map("htmlspecialchars", $row)) ?></td></tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: that's 1, pad it and you get paid more :-)

Comment: @Dagon That makes it 6 if you count the html :)

Comment: Thats what I was after!  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use json_decode() http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

That should help you I would think

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file_get_contents` and a `foreach` loop and `var_dump` to print the contents:

```
$data= json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ridetimes.co.uk/queue-times.php"), true);
foreach ($data as $row) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```